# Google doesn't crawl or index all my pages

Tags: seo, shopify, google-index

I have submit many times to index all pages but google index only nearly 1000 pages out of 13000 pages. Can you please explain what is the issue behind this. My website link is [here](http://www.barcelona-designs.com)

Answer (score 2):

[Google isn't guaranteed to index all of your pages.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34441?hl=en)

But you can encourage it to index more with a couple of steps. Have you tried [submitting your sitemap?](https://help.shopify.com/manual/using-themes/find-site-map)